# Generating Angular code in array notation with CoffeeScript (minification safe)

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

In Angular, to prevent minification errors you need to use array notation (example below). How can I achieve this output in CoffeeScript? I'm still learning so this is quite a hurdle for me.

## Example of Angular directive

```
app.directive('enterKey', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.enterKey);
                }, +attrs.enterKeyDelay);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The CoffeeScript to achieve this is:

```
app.directive 'enterKey', ($timeout) ->
    (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        elem.bind 'keydown', (e) ->
            if e.keyCode is 13
                $timeout ->
                    scope.$apply attrs.enterKey
                , +attrs.enterKeyDelay
```

## Desired Output

This is minification safe, it has an array wrapping the content and names of dependencies being imported.
The difference is subtle, its just an array with strings wrapping the content, but I'm not sure how to achieve this

```
app.directive('enterKey', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.enterKey);
                }, +attrs.enterKeyDelay);
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Look into [ng-classify](https://github.com/CaryLandholt/ng-classify#overview), it provides a simple way to write angular classes for controllers/directives/services/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use it like this:

```
app.directive 'enterKey',['$timeout', ($timeout) ->
    (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        elem.bind 'keydown', (e) ->
            if e.keyCode is 13
                $timeout ->
                    scope.$apply attrs.enterKey
                , +attrs.enterKeyDelay
]
```

`coffee -p` output:

```
app.directive('enterKey', [
  '$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      return elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          return $timeout(function() {
            return scope.$apply(attrs.enterKey);
          }, +attrs.enterKeyDelay);
        }
      });
    };
  }
]);
```